# Why do we always need the Schwarz lemma when bounding the trace of a Kähler metric?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I posted [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207959/), and while it has received some upvotes, it is not getting much attention. Perhaps it is more relevant here?

My undergraduate thesis topic is Kähler geometry. The general direction is something like the Calabi-Yau theorem or more adventurously some singular Calabi-Yau theorem, but this is not certain yet. One thing that I am noticing a lot of in my reading of Kähler geometry is that if we have two Kähler metrics $\omega$, $\eta$, then to get a bound of the form $$\text{tr}_{\omega}(\eta) \leq C$$ we need to use the Schwarz lemma -- Essentially, we apply the maximum principle to some term like $$\log \text{tr}_{\omega}(\eta) - A \varphi,$$ where $\omega = \eta + dd^c \varphi$ and $A>0$ is large. This requires an assumption on the (Ricci/bisectional/holomorphic sectional) curvatures of $\omega$, $\eta$ (depending on which Laplacian one computes with).

**I feel that I understand how to use the Schwarz lemma to get these estimates, but I want to ask why we have to use it (if we have to?).**

This is prompted by studying singular metrics, for examples cone and cusp metrics: To formulate my question, let $D$ be a divisor in a compact Kähler manifold $M$, and for simplicity, assume that $D$ has simple normal crossings. A cone Kähler metric is a Kähler metric which is smooth on $M - D$ and is quasi-isometric to $$\frac{i}{2} \sum_{j=1}^k | z_j |^{2(1-\beta_j)} dz_j \wedge d\overline{z}_j + \frac{i}{2} \sum_{j \geq k+1} dz_j \wedge d\overline{z}_j.$$

A cusp Kähler metric is a smooth Kähler metric on $M-D$ which is quasi-isometric to $$\frac{i}{2} \sum_{j=1}^k | z_j |^{-2}| \log | z_i |^2 |^{-2} dz_j \wedge d\overline{z}_j + \frac{i}{2} \sum_{j \geq k+1} dz_j \wedge d\overline{z}_j.$$

From these descriptions, can one not see immediately that if $\omega$ is cusp and $\eta$ is cone, then $$\text{tr}_{\omega}(\eta) \leq C | z_i|^{2\beta_i} | \log | z_i |^2|^2,$$ which would give $$\text{tr}_{\omega}(\eta) \leq C | \sigma_j |^{2\beta_j} | \log | \sigma_j |^2 |^2,$$ if $\sigma_j$ are the defining sections for the divisor $D$?

What initially came to my mind is a coordinate dependence problem, but this seems to contradict the fact that many calculations of this type involve normal coordinate calculations.

Sorry if this question is silly.

Comment: You don't *have* to use Schwarz lemma. There are many ways to compute $\Delta \log \mathrm{tr}_{\omega}(\eta)$ for two Kähler metrics $\omega, \eta$, e.g. using Chern-Lu's formula or Siu's formula. 
In the second part of your message, the trace controls are wrong. On the RHS, you should just have a (large) constant since a cusp metric dominate some multiple of a cone metric.
Finally, the "Laplaciane formulas" are intrinsic (they compute intrisic quantities like the the derivatives of the trace of a metric with respect to another one), but they can be proved using any system of coordinates.

Comment: @Henri Thank you for this detailed response. I was a little broad with the use of the expression _Schwarz lemma_, I did mean to also include the Chern-Lu inequality (thank you for bringing my attention to the Siu formula, your papers are beautiful to read).

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, the trace inequalites are still wrong as soon as the dimension is larger than one (in the trace, you have to incorporate the eigenvalues in directions tangent to the divisor, where both metrics are ("co-normally") euclidian). So it should be a constant instead.

Comment: @Henri Thank you for this additional feedback, I find this "co-normal" stuff quite difficult.